# Как рандомно вывести определенное количество элементов?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Здравствуйте! Подскажите, пожалуйста, а как рандомно вывести определенное количество элементов, а не один? Благодарю!

```js
$(function() {
  var divs = $('#elements div'),
    div;
  div = divs.eq(Math.floor(Math.random() * divs.length));
  div.show()
});
```

```css
#elements div {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="elements">
  <div id="container-1">
    Текст 1
  </div>
  <div id="container-2">
    Текст 2
  </div>
  <div id="container-3">
    Текст 3
  </div>
  <div id="container-4">
    Текст 4
  </div>
  <div id="container-5">
    Текст 5
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$(function() {
  var n = 2,
      divs = $('#elements div'),
      div;

  divs.sort(function (a, b) {return Math.random() - 0.5;});

  for (var i=0; i < n; ++i) {
      divs.eq(i).show();
  }
});
```

```css
#elements div {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="elements">
  <div id="container-1">
    Текст 1
  </div>
  <div id="container-2">
    Текст 2
  </div>
  <div id="container-3">
    Текст 3
  </div>
  <div id="container-4">
    Текст 4
  </div>
  <div id="container-5">
    Текст 5
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: интересный способ) не знаю, можно ли так делать, [на mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) так написано: `compareFunction(a, b) must always return the same value when given a specific pair of elements a and b as its two arguments. If inconsistent results are returned then the sort order is undefined.`

Comment: @LADYX, деление интервала 0...1 пополам https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random

Comment: @LADYX, с `display: none;` и `show();` не может быть ни какой ротации, так как идет просто показ блоков, но не их перестановка. Чтобы была перестановка, нужно все блоки `divs` вырезать из DOM и вставить их по новой в порядке полученном при `sort()` массива.

Answer (score 3):

- Создаем массив индексов, например используя [`lodash.range()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#range) ([или так](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33352604/5812238): `[...Array(длина).keys()]`)
- Случайно перемешиваем этот массив, например используя [`lodash.shuffle()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#shuffle) (или [так](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2450954/5812238))
- Берём первые несколько элементов этого массива и показываем div'ы с соответствующим номером

```js
const numberDivsToShow = 4;

$(function() {
  let divs = $('#elements div');
  let indexes = _.shuffle(_.range(divs.length));
  for (let i = 0; i < numberDivsToShow; ++i) {
    let divIndex = indexes[i];
    divs.eq(divIndex).show();
  }
});
```

```css
#elements div {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
<div id="elements">
  <div id="container-1">
    Текст 1
  </div>
  <div id="container-2">
    Текст 2
  </div>
  <div id="container-3">
    Текст 3
  </div>
  <div id="container-4">
    Текст 4
  </div>
  <div id="container-5">
    Текст 5
  </div>
</div>
```